# nginx + uwsgi for multiple sites using multiple ports

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I would like to host 2 sites in one IP address 1.2.3.4 for example. **I want to visit them by using different ports.** For example, I would like to have 1.2.3.4:8000 for siteA, while 1.2.3.4:9000 to point to siteB. I am using nginx + uwsgi.

Here is the example to configure one of sites. 
For NGINX, I had:

```
server {
listen   8000; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
location / {
    uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 1800;
    }   
}
```

For UWSGI, I had:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
master = true
harakiri = 60
listen = 5000
limit-as = 512
reload-on-as = 500
reload-on-rss = 500
pidfile = /tmp/uwsgi.pid
daemonize = /tmp/uwsgi.log
**chdir = /home/siteA**
module = wsgi_app
plugins = python
```

To visit siteA, I simple go to 1.2.3.4:8000.

I have no problem with configuration of one site, but I have no idea to make it working with two sites.
Please note that I didnot bind the site with the server name. Does it matter?
Thanks in advance.

P.S. The following is the way I launch NGINX and UWSGI.
I first put the nginx conf file (for siteA, I called it as siteA_for_ngxing.conf) in the **/etc/nginx/sites-available/** directory.

I then use **uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini** to start uwsgi. (the file of uwsgi.ini contains the above [uwsgi])...
Any help?

Comment: Have you try to add `server{ listen 9000; ... }`

Comment: well, if i put server{ listen 9000; ... } . then when i go to 1.2.3.4:9000. I still visit siteA. The problem I think is from the chdir = /home/siteA in UWSGI setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example might be useless for you, because it seems you installed uWSGI manually, instead of using system repository. But I think, you can easly find how uWSGI is configured on Ubuntu and make the same configuration on your system.

Here how I have done it on Ubuntu. I installed both uWSGI and nginx from Ubuntu repo, so I got the following dirs:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
/etc/uwsgi/apps-available
/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled
```

On `/etc/uwsgi/apps-available` I placed two files: `app_a.ini` and `app_b.ini`. There is no option `socket` (as well as `pid` and `daemonize`) in these files. uWSGI will detect socket, log, and pid file names using ini-file name.  Then I created symlink to these files in `/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled` to enable apps.

For nginx I used `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` config file (it already symlinked to `enabled` dir).

```
upstream app_a {
    server unix:///run/uwsgi/app/app_a/socket;
}
upstream app_b {
    server unix:///run/uwsgi/app/app_b/socket;
}

server {
    listen 8000;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass app_a;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
server {
    listen 9000;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass app_b;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, @dmitry-vakhrushev thank you for your nice post. I still am not able to make it correctly. I have done what you said. I also restart the nginx and uwsgi??? When i now go to different sites, it gave me 502 Bad Gateway... Meanwhile, where can i find the log files for uwsgi?

Comment: Hi @StudentJack, did you check uWSGI logs? It should be placed on /var/log/uwsgi/

Comment: Hi  @dmitry-vakhrushev... you win. the website gives up by showing me the correct way that it is supposed to be. This is great. Thanks.

Comment: out of curiosity, when i did what you showed above, it seems like i have the permission issue. For instance, i used to have some codes (in the website) to write some contents to a file. But now it fails. Any thought?

Comment: It might happen because uWSGI runs behalf a system user (www-data is default one on Ubuntu).